# How are abilities unlocked in the Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

On the character attributes page is a section for abilities (different from talents). I've earned the abilites Axii sign hex, cover, conjuror and assassin. Each of those gives a certain bonus, which is nice, but I have no idea how I unlocked most of those abilities.

I got the Axii sign hex when I first used Axii in a conversation, but I've no clue how I unlocked the rest of them. Are they given to you on certain events, or do you have to do something special to get them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These abilities are gained by performing specific actions, but they're not revealed to you until after you've done them. Some examples:

- As you mentioned, Axii is received after first using it in conversation.
- Assassin is received after [locating Altair's body](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22510/where-can-i-find-altair) in the prologue.
- Cover is received by staying under Triss's magic shield for the duration of that event at the start of chapter 1 ([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/59145097)).

Some of these are possible to miss, so it pays to be an explorer and a completionist.

Comment: I've left the shield for short times and still got the cover ability, I would consider that one suspect.